# Flutter and Whatsapp Group

Tags: flutter, whatsapp

I managed to send whatsapp messages from my app with

```
launchWhatsapp(String num) async {
  String url;

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    url = "https://wa.me/$num/?text=${Uri.parse('test')}"; // new line
  } else {
    url =
        "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$num=${Uri.parse('test')}"; // new line
  }

  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

but I need to send the same message to multiple numbers, so how can I achieve this?

I can't use a loop because in that case the user should anyway confirm manually one by one so it would become very annoying.

I was thinking about creating a whatsapp group, but apparently that's not possible from flutter. Or maybe that's not the correct solution.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you get any solution on this? Even I am working on a similar scenario and was eager to know if you got any solution to this. Thanks

Comment: @Sampat no unfortunately I didn't find any solution. I gave up using whatsapp and I implemented a chat with firebase